# WPF - adding user control to listbox

Tags: wpf, user-controls

I am trying to add a **usercontrol** to a **ListBox**.

My usercontrol contains a collection of basic elements like textbox and dropdowns, in a fashion so that it creates a row of elements.

The code for ListBox in my main window is as  -

```
<GroupBox FontWeight="SemiBold" Foreground="#FF0CAEF9" Name="gbAddProducts" Style="{x:Null}" Header="ADD PRODUCTS" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,256,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="990" Height="207">
        <ListBox Name="lstboxAddProduct" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=AddNewProductRowViewModelList, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" BorderThickness="0" Margin="0,10,-2,23">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                            <ContentControl Content="{Binding AddNewProductRowViewModel}" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <Validation.ErrorTemplate>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <StackPanel>
                            <AdornedElementPlaceholder x:Name="aepForError"/>
                            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding}">
                                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ErrorContent}"  Foreground="White" Background="#DC000C" />
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                            </ItemsControl>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Validation.ErrorTemplate>
            </ListBox>

        </GroupBox>
```

Here **AddNewProductRowViewModelList** is my user control list containing 5 controls.
The Problem that I see is that when I run the code, the screen has 5 rows, ie I can click on the area to figure out theer are 5 rows as that section gets highlighted. But they are not visible.

Could it be some 'bring to front' sort of issue.

Please advise.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the AddNewProductRowViewModel that you bind the ContentControl to?    You should bind it to each item from the AddNewProductRowViewModelList.

Comment: AddNewProductRowViewModel is the model for the user control. I gave the Binding of ListBox to the List of UserControls - AddNewProductRowViewModelList. I thought that was clear enough from the code.

Comment: Maybe you should put a converter with a breakpoint on that Binding to see what the ContentControl is recieving.

Comment: I do not see how your list would know about the other view that user control which represents a row. Can you explain how you understand that connection is happening. The content property accepts a view (grid stack panel or other control) and if you are using MVVM as your property suggests then you assign a view model which is not a view.

Comment: @Rafal - I will try to explain . There exists a user control - AddNewProductRowView. In the user control I have provided the DataContxt as AddNewProductRowViewModel (which is a model of course). When I open it independently, it works good as expected. Now, in my main window I added a List (the above code). The MainWidow has its DataContext set to a Model which in turn contains a List of AddNewProductRowViewModel  - ObservableCollection<AddNewProductRowViewModel> AddNewProductRowViewModelList. In this Model I add Five User Controls in the constructor of mainWindow View Model.

Comment: Can you post the constructor of your mainWindow view model please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would do it this way instead:

```
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
   <DataTemplate>
      <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
         <ContentControl>
            <local:AddNewProductRowView Datacontext="{Binding AddNewProductRowViewModel}"/>
          </ContentControl>
         </StackPanel>
       </DataTemplate>
     </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: Cool !! You have hit the nail on its head...This is what I have been missing. Thanks a ton .